# ETCD v3.5 support API v2

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

Is there is any way to make ETCD v3.5 support API v2? I have installed etcd v3.5 but I do not see that it is supportes in API v2

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR;

Check `--enable-v2` and `--experimental-enable-v2v3` flags.

Docs: https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/op-guide/configuration/

## More reading

Those flags will be removed in etcd 3.6 ([v2 deprecation plan](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/12913)), so please consider migration to v3 ([migration documentation](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/op-guide/v2-migration/)).